# Top Down Modulation Two Layer Network

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have this simple two-layer feedforward network that is going to classify MNIST digits. With this network, I get satisfiable accuracies, but I want to modify it slightly. Following a paper by [Shrivastava et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06851), I want incorporate their top-down modulation without the lateral modules (see page 3). Also, I want to keep it limited to these two layers, so not create a deeper network. Basically, in the new network, as opposed to the simple feedforward network below, the second layer is connected again to the first layer to achieve this top-down feedback link.

I have no idea how to go about it, and after considerable online digging I haven't found any other source code/examples on how to do this in TensorFlow (or any other library for that matter). Any help or a push in the right direction is much appreciated!

```
# PREVENTS VANISHING GRADIENT PROBLEM
stddev1=np.sqrt(2 / float(784))
# second = 10 units
stddev2=np.sqrt(2 / float(10))

w1 = tf.get_variable('w1',[784,10],
                     initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=stddev1))
b1 = tf.get_variable('b1',[10,],
                     initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
# relu has vanishing gradient problem
z1 = tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1
y1 = tf.nn.relu(z1) # 

# layer 2
w2 = tf.get_variable('w2',[10,10],
                 initializer= tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0,stddev=stddev2))
b2 = tf.get_variable('b2',[10,],
                     initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y1, w2) + b2, name="output")

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect your second layer to your first layer, it will be Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) and not top-down modulation,

The paper you mention actually didn't do anything like what you say, they only use their previous layers in front layers, actually, they do like skip-connection.

Skip-connections (or skip layers) is something like this:[image]

As you can see after sip-layer we use `add` function to aggregate two layers into one, But the paper to implement top-down modulation use 'Lateral Modules' in order to connect previous layers to next layers directly.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. That is perhaps for a later stage. What I want to accomplish is that z2 is added to x (input image) and that z1 is calculated from the sum of x and z2. Should I use RNN cells / LSTM cells for this? Then would something like this work (this is single layer right?): [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/rnn-tensorflow-python-machine-learning-tutorial/)

Comment: If you want to do like this: ( layer1 = x + z1, layer2 = x + layer1 ) so there is no need to RNN, and the link you shared use more than one layer.